# A Condition for Semiconcavity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

This is a question regarding Evan's PDE (2nd edition), Section 3.3.3.

We say that a function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is *semiconcave* if there exists a constant $C$ such that for all $x, z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ,

$$g(x + z) - 2g(x) + g(x - z) \leq C ||z||^2.$$

Evans claims that "it is easy to check" that $g$ is semiconcave if $g \in C^2$ and

$$\sup_{y \in \mathbb R^n} \left\|D^2g(y)\right\|_2 < \infty$$

where the norm on the Hessian is just the usual $\ell_2$ norm, viewing $D^2g(y)$ as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Despite the remark in the book, I am not finding this easy to check -- how can I show that $g$ is semiconcave under these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, \begin{align*}
g(x+z)-2g(x)+g(x-z) &= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} \big ( g(x+tz)\big ) \, dt + \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} \big ( g(x-tz)\big ) \, dt \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nz_i\int_0^1   \partial_i g(x+tz)-\partial_ig(x-tz)   \, dt .
\end{align*} Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus again, gives \begin{align*}
g(x+z)-2g(x)+g(x-z) &=\sum_{i=1}^nz_i\int_0^1 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{d} {d\tau} \partial_i g(x+t\tau z)\, dt \\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^nz_iz_j\int_0^1 \int_{-1}^1 t\partial_{ij} g(x+t\tau z)\, dt \\
&\leqslant2 \| D^2 g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)} \vert z \vert^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: This is minor, but should it not be (in the penultimate line) $\sum_{i,j =1}^n z_i z_J \int_0^1 \int_{-1}^1 \partial_{ij} g(x + t \tau z) t d \tau d t$?

Comment: I agree. I’ve updated my answer

Comment: @JackT First of all I apologize for search you here in a place that it is not supposed to me to comment here. But, please, help me with this? I only would like at least a hint, a small tip. Please, help me, I know from your profile that you are good at pde classic theory. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797950/what-hypothesis-can-i-assum-in-order-to-obtain-infinity-solutions-for-this-probl